# Non-Blocking UI WPF/Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, nonblocking, system.reactive

What are the things to be kept in mind while designing a non-blocking UI. Is IObservable meant for that?

Comment: in silverlight you do not have a choice, you cannot use any blocking api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also very interesting idea of [coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) when working with async methods.

You can read abut it here:

1. [Asycnhronous Service Calls with Coroutines](http://matthamilton.net/async-service-calls-coroutines)
2. [Coroutines with MVVM Light](http://matthamilton.net/coroutines-with-mvvm-light)
3. [IResult and Coroutines](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=IResult%20and%20Coroutines&referringTitle=Documentation)

Answer (score 1):

I think most general rule would be: All long-lasting operations, like database or service calls should be run either asynchronouly or in separate thread or backgrounworker.